# comparing two 'card' objects in Java

Tags: java, oop, compareto

I'm stuck on this question where I need to compare two card objects based upon what rank and suit they are.
Heart being the lowest suit, Spades the highest.
And for Rank, One the lowest and Ace the highest.
And 5 Spades being > 2 Hearts.
These values are stored in two enums of their respective type. With Heart being the first ordinal and Spades the last ordinal.

```
@Override
    public int compareTo(Card o) {
        
        if(this.rank.ordinal() > o.rank.ordinal()) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (this.rank.ordinal() < o.rank.ordinal()) {
            return -1;
        } 
        else {
            return 0;
        }
```

In my comapreTo() I've implemented the comparing of the rank, but I'm stuck on THEN comparing the suit to find the greater card. This code fails once it goes past Ace of Hearts as it thinks 1 of clubs is higher. I've tried a bunch of different methods using if's but it just becomes convoluted and ugly and doesn't work anyways. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Generally, you want to *first* compare the highest-relevance one (which seems to be rank) and *if* that is equal, then compare the next one (and so on, if there's more than two). So instead of `return 0` you just start another `if-then`-cascade comparing `suit`. Also: Using `Integer.compareTo` can simplify your code: `int result = Integer.compareTo(this.rank.ordinal(), o.rank.ordinal()); if (result == null) { /* further tests, assigning to result */ }; return result;`

Comment: @JoachimSauer `result == null` always evaluates to false. I suppose you wanted `0`.

Comment: @Hulk: absolutely, that was a brain-fart.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way would be to use the *Comparator* interface and its static factory methods introduced in Java8:

```java
private final Comparator<Card> comparator = Comparator.comparingInt((Card card) -> card.rank.ordinal())
        .thenComparing((Card card) -> card.suit.ordinal());
```

You can then use this comparator directly, or through the overridden `compareTo` method:

```java
@Override
public int compareTo(Card other) {
    return comparator.compare(this, other);
}
```

---

Since this question is also tagged with `oop`, I'll add that the whole comparison logic should belong to a card *game*, not to the card itself.

In other words, if this comparison is game-specific, you should avoid putting it inside your entity/model. Asa result, you'll be able to easily reuse the `Card` object for different card `games`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Comparator.comparing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html):

I understand `rank` is having priority over the `suit`, so it can be done like:

```java
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Cards {

  enum Suit {hearts, clubs, diamonds, spades}

  enum Rank {_2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, joker, queen, king, ace,}

  record Card(Suit suit, Rank rank) implements Comparable<Card> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Card o) {
      return Comparator.comparing(Card::rank).thenComparing(Card::suit).compare(this, o);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    var c1 = new Card(Suit.hearts, Rank.ace);
    var c2 = new Card(Suit.spades, Rank._2);
    System.out.println(c1.compareTo(c2));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the further comparison into the else:

```
@Override
    public int compareTo(Card o) {
        
        if(this.rank.ordinal() > o.rank.ordinal()) {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (this.rank.ordinal() < o.rank.ordinal()) {
            return -1;
        } 
        else {
            if (this.suit.ordinal() > o.suit.ordinal()) {
                return 1;
            }
            else if (this.suit.ordinal() < o.suit.ordinal()) {
                return -1;
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }
```